# Python categorize functions

Tags: python-2.7, categorization

Is there any way to Categorize Functions
so that I could call a function like this:

```
category something():
    def test():
        [Code]

    def test2():
        [Code]

something.test()
something.test2()
```

I thought of using classes, but it seems like they always need an instance e.g. self as an attribute.

If I'm wrong please feel free to correct me, I am kind of new to python and don't have that much experience.

For now, I've been using different files for that but I often ran into circular dependency issues and wanted to ask if there's an easy solution to this problem.

This is for cleaning up the code a bit and to know to which part of a scipt a function may belong when you have lots of code.

Comment: What is the purpose of "categorizing" functions? Do you want to create 2 functions with the same name? Or just organize them in a way that they belong to the same "thing/category"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need an instance - you can declare each method as (or, actually, transform it into) a "static" method:

```
class Foo:

    @staticmethod 
    def Bar(x, y):
        return x + y

    @staticmethod 
    def Baz(x, y):
        return x - y

print(Foo.Bar(3, 4))
```

The interpretation of the first argument as a reference to the instance (conventionally, but not necessarily, called `self`) does not happen in static methods.

But creating classes full of static methods would be a somewhat off-label use of `class`.  The more common way to categorize resources in Python is to divide them into [modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) (i.e. separate files and/or directories):

```
# in Foo.py
def Bar(x, y):
    return x + y
```

and then:

```
>>> import Foo
>>> Foo.Bar(3, 4)
7
```

Comment: so i'll just have to write @staticmethod infront of every function i'm defining? Or can i make a whole class into static methods by adding it somewhere at the beginning?

Comment: You would have to use the decorator every time.  But really: don't do it that way.  Use modules like the rest of us.